# Google Drive API limit Project to Specific folder with Read only access

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-drive-api

We are looking to create a project for access to a specific folder with Read only permission.
My question is when creating the project what ways are there to limit access and permission in the project itself?
Can this be done? and is it through the enable APIs. I have done some reading on this and I cannot find a conclusive answer.
What APIs would I need enabled to apply this.

I will not be in control of any scripts, this will be a project for web application.

The scenario of what we have is Many thousands of files with in google drive, we want to give access to a specific folder and not have the ability to go through the rest of our google drive. They will be using Javascript to download files from this and upload automatically in to a system at there end, they are looking to use the Google drive API to do this.

Look forward to your replys opinions and direction on this.
Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

you cannot do this at the project console level. you are missing info like how the webapp authenticates the user or whether the drive api calls are server side or client side. but in either case what you need is to never use the drive owner account and simply share that folder readonly public or to specific emails.

for a more detailed answer you need to explain much better the scenario.